# Issues with docker

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, containers, visual-studio-2019

I'm having a lot of issues using docker for a C# application.

Here's the first issue I have: I need to run an image in a docker container running on port 8080. I have tried everything inside Visual Studio 2019 but I can't find a way to make it run on port 8080. Basically when I click on the play button it ignores the entry EXPOSE 8080/tcp of dockerfile and runs the image in a container on a random port.

I have tried running the immage from the command line by using "docker run -d -p 8080:80 aspnetapp" where 'aspnetapp' is the name of the image. Everything seems fine and and in Docker Desktop I can see it was trying to run on port 8080 but the container exits with error code 0.

When I run from Visual Studio everything works fine but I can't change to port 8080.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProductDirectory.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./ProductDirectory.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "ProductDirectory.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProductDirectory.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
EXPOSE 8080/tcp

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProductDirectory.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use multiple stage inside your Dockerfile.
but you should be careful about that because Docker take only the latest part of your dockerfile , in your case it's take only this part :

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProductDirectory.dll"]
```

where you didn't define the port for your application .
to resolve this issue just add EXPOSE port and specify your port for this section, like that:

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProductDirectory.dll"]
```

And I hope that can help you to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue is not solved. I changed my code as you adviced but the container is still running on a random port, currently on port 49175 and I don't really know how to change it. I tried eveything

Comment: `EXPOSE` doesn't really do anything in modern Docker, and it's not strictly required here.